# git and eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, version-control

I am totally lost on git, I read the docs but do not have a clue.  I have been using CVS for decades and just need some help getting setup.

- I have a linux machine I setup a git repository on (created a directory and ran git init).  I have ssh access to the machine.
- I have an eclipse java project that I would like to commit/push whatever to this git repository.
- I installed egit in Eclipse, but it does not give me any options to setup a url or hostname:port etc.
- Further it wants to make the repository where I have the project in the same directories.  That cannot be right.

How do I get eclipse to commit this to the git repository on my linux machine?

I have no idea what people see in this program, I was never confused with CSV but now noone supports or allows CVS anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design goals of a git are explained well [in The git parable](http://tom.preston-werner.com/2009/05/19/the-git-parable.html)

It may help with the required paradigm shift moving from CVS.

git was developed for the purpose of controlling submissions to the Linux kernel so the design goal of supporting the version control a large distributed project was a key one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your thinking.  In particular, you say "Further it wants to make the repository where I have the project in the same directories. That cannot be right".  But it is right.  The repository is local.  That is one of the fundamental differences from CVS.  Make all of your changes in the local repository, and only push to a remote when you want to publish.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider local repository as a "smart" working directory. It is still possible to have centralized integration repository,  similar to central repository in CVS with slightly different terms:

- "check-in to repository" now is "push to integration repository"
- "check-out from repository" now is "pull from integration repositoty"

Real magic begins after repository is cloned to the local computer. You get working directory and a lot of new opportunities.

- Multiple developer branches in the same working directory. You may work with several features independently at the same time and switch easily between them. For example, I have branches for fixes of bugs (one branch per bug), and new features in the same repository (branch per feature). Switch is pair of commands/clicks
- You can do frequent local commits of partially done work, and rollback quickly to any state of the repository. After feature is done or bug is fixed, you may "polish" history by combining and re-arranging commits before "push to integraton repository"
- There are good opportunities to dig the project history, and this is really fast: all history is already on your computer
- You can easily transfer changes from one branch to another. If for example, particular change is useful in several branches

Answer (score 0):

Git is a distributed version control system (DVCS). This means you will have a repository on your local machine. You will need to read up on "pushing", "fetching" and "pulling". This is all under the idea of "remotes" - how you tell one repository where another one lives.

You can expect that there will be a .git folder in the root of your working directory.

I would do a quick read up on git at any of the following places:

```
gitready.com
progit.org/book
git-scm.com
```

There is also the #git channel on freenode.

Comment: Does that mean it sits in the directory where my project is?

Comment: Also then how do I on Windows push this to the proper location on my Linux machine so that others can use it?

Comment: @Bodger, yes, your working directory and your local repository are the same thing. You can clone your linux repository to a local repository on your windows machine, and then commit from the windows machine to push the changes out to the linux repository.

Comment: You will need to either add the remote with "git remote add origin <url of the linux repo>" or if it already exists, "git clone <url of the linux repo>"

Comment: You should also make a decision early on if you will be developing for one plat form and if so, set the autocrlf setting to false. Do the same on anyone else's repo or they will have issues with line endings differences registering as changes where there are none. hope this helps.

Comment: OK now I have a local repository in my eclipse project.  And now I want to push it and it is asking me things that continue to befuddle me.   What is a "source ref" and a "destination ref"?